# How to mock a method of kotlin object class using MockK

Tags: kotlin, mockk

I've an kotlin object class like the one below

```kotlin
object DummyClass {

    fun method1() {}
}
```

and i want to mock the function `method1()` using **MockK** library

since this is an object class method of mocking a normal function not working on it, what i've tried is as shown below

also tried some other approaches but it didn't worked

```
@Test
fun method1Test() {
    val mock = mockk<DummyClass>()
    every { mock.method1() } just runs
    DummyClass.method1()
}
```

i've seen some questions here on StackOverflow, still haven't found any solution for my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To apply mocking on a Object class we can simply use `mockkObject(ObjectClassName)` and mocking method of that class is exactly same as for other method `every { ObjectClassName.methodName() } just runs`

After looking for solution over **StackOverflow** and **Google**

I found solution of my problem on [official documentation of MockK](https://mockk.io/)

I've added a screen shot of my finding here, keeping this question hope it might help someone

[image]